# sidekiq background job to send email and heroku worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, background-process, sidekiq

Sorry for the basic question about Sidekiq's delaying ActionMailer. As per [this article](http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2013/01/using-sidekiq-to-send-emails-asynchronously), Sidekiq can delay sending out emails by just saying `UserMailer.delay_for(1.hour)....`.

Does this mean this is handled in the background now, or does it mean that it simply just delays sending the email out for an hour but once that hour comes, then the email is basically being sent like a regular ActionMailer, which slows down response time?

Or is it that if I truly want to do this in the background then I would have to do the other sidekiq stuff like putting it in a specific Worker and then firing it up that way?

Also, separately, if I do just do it via `UserMailer.delay...`, I presume I won't need a worker dyno on Heroku to save some money, correct?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, for emails you don't need to do anything else. It's like calling the Mailer 1 hour later. You just need to make sure you don't pass any complex objects into the mailer, for example a user object, you should only pass the user_id, because it will be stored in redis. On the Mailer fetch the user object with the given id.

Comment: Thanks, so this won't slow down response time on the site when Mailer sends out say, 100 emails 1 hour later?

Also, as for passing in any complex objects, does that mean it is not recommended to do any computational stuff in the mailer, like find all users with the last name Smith?  I know this is better done in the model, but I am asking for example purposes.

Also, would I still need a worker dyno on Heroku?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, your response time will not be affected because the mailer work is done at background (and later). You should only pass simple data, like integers, strings and arrays of those. And again yes, you need an extra dyno on heroku.